# How to identify whether a download is completed using an ashx handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, httphandler, ashx

In one of our project we need the functionality to download a file from server to client location.

For this we are using an ashx handler to do the operation. Its working perfectly and we are able to download files.

Now we need a requirement like we need to update a field when a download is started and completed. Is there any way to do this.

Once we click the download link the Save as dialog box will appear and after that i think we don't have any control to check the progress. I think we even don't know which button is clicked ie we don't know whether the user is clicked a 'Yes' or 'No'.

Can anyone please suggest a method to know when the download is started and when it has been completed? We are using Asp.Net 2.0 with c#.

The handler used for download is given below

```
               string fileUrl = string.Empty;

                if (context.Request["fileUrl"] != null)
                {
                    fileUrl = context.Request["fileUrl"].ToString();                    
                }
                string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileUrl);

                context.Response.ClearContent();
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/exe";
                context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", filename));
                context.Response.TransmitFile(fileUrl);
                context.Response.Flush();
```

The file is downloaded from an aspx page method like

```
private void DownloadExe()
{
  string downloadUrl = "Test.exe");
  Response.Redirect("Test.ashx?fileUrl=" + downloadUrl, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ASHX handler knwos if download started (since it is actually get called) and when download is completed (end of handler is reached). You may even get some progress server side if you are writing response manually in chunks, this way you also may be able to detect some cases when user cancels download (if writing to response stream fails at some point).

Depending on your needs you may be able to transfer this information to other pages (i.e. via session state) or simply store in some database.

Comment: Yes, when we click on the handler means i think download is about to start.But now also user got the option to either click Yes or No to do or cancel the download. I didn't get you on how to know when download is started or cancelled.  Can you please suggest any samples on the web. Thank you..

Comment: The only thing you reasonably can see is GET request to you ASHX handler on server. You have no control over how browser shows UI and at what point it gives user choice to save/open/cancel. If you want something beyond GET started/response sent/connection close you will have to build you own download client (not possible with browser).

Comment: So how the handler know when a download is started and also when it is completed?

Comment: ? Handler handles request - start when request is started and complete when request is completed. There is exactly one function [ProcessRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.processrequest.aspx) - so I don't see where confusion about start/end comse from: starts at the beginning of function, ends when function completes (unless you are using async handlers which have 2 functions).

Comment: @Alexie : I think end of response doesn't means end of download. I just need a way to get when download is completed, i need to update a database entry.. I am searching a way for this.

Comment: "end of response doesn't means end of download" - you need to define what exactly you want and ask question about it.

Comment: sorry to disturb you.. as explained in my question, i need to update database when a download is started and when it is completed. But here when using handler, i know when the download is started. I have given the code i used. After we calling Response.Redirect, it will redirect to the handler page. A download dialog box will appear and immediately after that we got control back into our method. So how we know whether download started and when it is completed. Hope now you understand what i means..

Comment: Please figure out exactly what you mean "download completed" (as end of GET request does not seem to work for you) and ask new question. I don't see how I can help any father at this point. Sorry.

Comment: K..its k... thank you.."download completed" means the download of file is completed from the server... yes thats what i said in previous comment request end doesn't means the download is completed.

Comment: if we are using WebClient to download a file, we get the exact progress and when the download is completed. I want a similar functionality by sing handler.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
Response.BufferOutput = false;
Response.TransmitFile(fileUrl);
//download complete code
```

If you disable response output buffering then it won't move past the line of code that sends the file to the client until the client has finished receiving it. If they cancel the download half way through it throws a HttpException so the download complete code doesn't get run.

You could also place your download complete code after your call to flush the buffer. But it's better not to enable buffering when sending large binary files to save on server memory.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I had the same problem and jumped over this site:
[Check over coockies](http://gruffcode.com/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser/)

This works great for me.